# Finding functions such that $f(g(x)) = f(x)g(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let's assume the functions in question are continuously differentiable.
If $f(g(x)) = f(x)g(x)$, then:
$$f'(g(x))g'(x) = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
I attempted to find a particular solution by letting $g(x) = x$.
Then,
$$f'(x) = xf'(x) + f(x)$$
$$df = xdf + fdx$$
$$\frac{df}{f} = \frac{dx}{1-x}$$
$$\ln(f(x)) = -\ln(1-x)+C$$
$$f(x) = \frac {A}{1-x}$$
Where $A$ is a constant. This solution was fairly unsatisfying to me, and upon checking it, I see it doesn't actually work, as letting $g(x) = x$ leads to $f(x) = xf(x)$. I was wondering if there were better answers, or at least a less trivial way to go about the problem.

Comment: If $g(x)=x$ then $f(x)=f(x)x$. Now, for $x \ne 1$ it follows that $f(x)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, we get $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Just to clarify things. You want to find continuously differentiable $f$ such that it holds for arbitrary continuously differentiable functions $g$?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for two specific functions $f$ and $g$ such that this holds. I chose $g(x)=x$ here because I didn't know how to solve it generally, and $x $ seemed like a simple function to work with.

Comment: Is it a homework question ?

Comment: Besides, a little detail, do you agree with the change of title I suggest (functions with an "s") ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, this is not a homework question; just something I was curious about. Yes, the changes to the title look good to me.

Comment: One can look for solutions of the form $f(x)=x^{a}$ and $g(x)=x^{b}$ giving relationship $x^{ab}=x^{a+b}$ which is verified with $a=b=2$. I don't understand why @David Bowman has erased is answer: it is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is, that you look for solutions to 
$$ \tag{1} f(x) = xf(x) + c $$
for some $c \in \mathbf R$, as all those functions fulfill 
$$ f'(x) = xf'(x) + f(x) $$
your function fulfills (1) with $c = A$.

(1) Of course $f = 0$ fulfills your equation with any $g$.

(2)
Let's look for polynomials satisfying your equation, as for general functions I doubt there is a wholesome answer, you have to restrict yourself to some function class. If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ say, then $f \circ g$ has degree $nm$ and $fg$ has degree $n +m$. Hence, we must have (let's ignote the zero polynomial here, we discussed the 0-function above)
$$ nm = n +m \iff n(m-1) = m \iff n = \frac{m}{m-1}$$
As $\frac m{m-1}$ is only integer for $m \in\{0,2\}$, we must have $n=m=2$ or $n=m=0$. If both $f$ and $g$ are of degree $0$, i. e. constants, say $f(x) = a_0$ and $g(x) = b_0$, our eqation reads 
$$ (f \circ g)(x) = f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) = a_0 \stackrel!= a_0b_0 = f(x)g(x) $$
which is correct for $b_0 = 1$.
For $m = n = 2$, say $f(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ and $g(x) = b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0$ with $a_2b_2 \ne 0$, we have 
$$ 
  f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) = a_2b_2^2x^4 + r_1(x),\quad f(x)g(x) = a_2b_2x^4 + r_2(x) $$
for some polynomials $r_1$, $r_2$ of degree $3$. This gives $b_2 = 1$. Now let's have a look at the degree $3$ terms, we have 
\begin{align*}
  f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) &= a_2x^4 + 2a_2b_1x^3 + r_3(x)\\
  f(x)g(x)          &= a_2x^4 + (a_2b_1 + a_1)x^3 + r_4(x)
\end{align*}
for some polynomials of degree at most $2$. This gives 
$$ a_1 = a_2b_1 $$

\begin{align*}
  f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) &= a_2(b_2x^2 + b_1 x + b_0) + a_1(b_2x^2+ b_1x + b_0) + a_0\\
   &= a_2b_2^2x^4 + 2a_2b_1b_2x^3 + (2a_2b_2b_0 + a_2b_1^2 + a_1b_2)x^2\\&\qquad{} + (2a_2b_1b_0 + a_1b_1)x + (a_2b_0^2 + a_1b_0 + a_0)\\
  f(x)g(x) &= (a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0)(b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0)\\
   &= a_2b_2x^4 + (a_2b_1 + a_1b_2)x^3 + (a_2b_0 + a_1b_1 + a_0b_2)x^2 + (a_1b_0 + a_0b_1)x + a_0b_0
\end{align*}
This gives 
\begin{align*}
   a_2b_2 &= a_2b_2^2\\
  2a_2b_1b_2 &= a_2b_1 + a_1b_2\\
  2a_2b_2b_0 + a_2b_1^2 + a_1b_2 &= a_2b_0 + a_1b_1 + a_0b_2\\
  2a_2b_1b_0 + a_1b_1 &= a_1b_0 + a_0b_1\\
  a_2b_0^2 + a_1b_0 + a_0 &= a_0b_0
\end{align*}
The first equation gives (due to $a_2b_2 \ne 0$ that $b_2 = 1$), we are left with 
\begin{align*}
  a_2b_1 &= a_1\\
  a_2b_0 + a_2b_1^2 + a_1 &= a_1b_1 + a_0\\
  2a_2b_1b_0 + a_1b_1 &= a_1b_0 + a_0b_1\\
  a_2b_0^2 + a_1b_0 + a_0 &= a_0b_0
\end{align*}
If we use the first equation in the second and the third to simplify further, we get 
\begin{align*}
  a_2b_1 &= a_1\\
  a_2b_0 + a_1 &= a_0\\
  a_1b_0 + a_1b_1 &= a_0b_1\\
  a_2b_0^2 + a_1b_0 + a_0 &= a_0b_0
\end{align*}
Now note that the third equation follows from the first two (multiply the second with $b_1$ and use the first), so we can drop it, giving
\begin{align*}
  a_2b_1 &= a_1\\
  a_2b_0 + a_1 &= a_0\\
  a_2b_0^2 + a_1b_0 + a_0 &= a_0b_0
\end{align*}
If we multiply the second equation with $b_0$ and subtract it from the third, we get 
$$ a_0= 0 $$
Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
  a_2b_1 &= a_1\\
  a_2b_0 + a_1 &= 0\\  
\end{align*}
Due to $a_2 \ne 0$, this gives $b_0 = -b_1$ and $a_1 = a_2b_1$. Hence we have 
\begin{align*}
   f(x) &= a_2x^2 + a_2b_1x\\
   g(x) &= x^2 + b_1x - b_1
\end{align*}
as a soultion for any $a_2 \in \mathbf R \setminus\{0\}$, $b_1 \in \mathbf R$.